# Es posible traer un listado de archivos en el cmd?

Tags: cmd, powershell

Conozco que existe el dir /b *directorio* pero estaría necesitando armar una lista de archivos con su fecha de creación incluida.
Algo asi:
Ejemplo.zip 25/06/2022
Ejemplo2.zip 24/06/2022

Answer (score 1):

Prueba así:

**`dir /TC directorio`**

**Mostrar resultados ordenados por tiempo:**

El uso del /T junto con un código de letra le permite ordenar los resultados por las diferentes marcas de tiempo asociadas con archivos y carpetas. Estos códigos de letras incluyen:

**R**: La hora en que se accedió por última vez al elemento.

**C**: La hora en que se creó el elemento.

**W**: La hora a la que se escribió por última vez el elemento. Esta es la opción predeterminada utilizada.

[Información extraída de aquí](https://www.howtogeek.com/363639/how-to-use-the-dir-command-in-windows/)

Comment: Mmm no me lista como necesito si bien ordena me lista con un encabezado de "El volumen de la unidad e es Nuevo vol... Etc "